# undefined method `fetch_value" after simple migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I made the migration to the base (in the user table, devise gem) where the column was deleted and a new one was created. After that, in the console (rails c) outputting all users will output:

`irb(main):003:0> User.all
 User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1 [["LIMIT", 11]]
(Object doesn't support #inspect) 
 =>`

If input `User.first` for example:

`irb(main):004:0> User.first
User Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
Traceback (most recent call last):1: from (irb):4
NoMethodError (undefined method`fetch_value' for nil:NilClass)]`

The application itself fell, it writes in the console the problem:

```
  `undefined method 'fetch_value' for nil: NilClass`
```

In Extracted source writes that problem in:
      `<% if user_signed_in? %>`

migration's code

`class RechangeFlagsToClass < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    remove_column :users, :flags
    add_column :users, :class, :integer, default: 5
  end
end`

Comment: is your table users has a content?, seems it cannot get any record when you type User.first,  you can test it with User.count, to check number of users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh, that was a mistake.

`class` is a reserved word.  You're not allowed to use it.  It's an object method that returns the class of an object, so if you have a User.object in the variable `my_boss` and you do `my_boss.class` you would see `User` returned.

Write another migration to remove `class` and add a different_method `class_number` or something.

Comment: That's right.  Otherwise there's no way for Rails to determine the class of the object because you've overridden the `class` method.

Comment: Nice!Steve I thank you very much, good luck for you. And you can still ask for one more thing, it is not in order to create a new issue. So here I am 19 years, I've been studying RoR for more than half a year. I am told that ruby loses its popularity. What do you advise me, given your beard, I hope for something clever)))

Comment: Yeah, I've heard that, too, but opinions vary.  https://www.quora.com/Is-the-Ruby-programming-language-on-the-decline  I would stick with it... the demand is there, and what you learn will be helpful even if you change to another OOP language. And grow a white beard, as you can always get extra work around Chirstmas time that way.